# SQL Query (written in Python) is return an error

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x

EDIT: The issue was I needed a space in the SQL Command that wasn't present. Some other users suggested I'm using some bad syntax, which might also be true, but this is all set now.

My query works fine in a .dqy file, or in microsoft sql studio, but it's presenting this error when I try to run it in Python:

> ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]"RMORHP" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is
>   intended as a parameter to a table-valued function or to the
>   CHANGETABLE function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is
>   set to 90. (321) (SQLExecDirectW)')

I'm not sure what that means or how to adjust my script. I assume I'm making a bad call somewhere but I don't know where. The database itself is an enterprise solution, so I need to change my query, not the database.

Code:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver=SQL Server;"
                      "Server=server;"
                      "Database=database;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
                      "APP=Microsoft Office 2010")
#cursor = cnxn.cursor()
SQLCommand =("SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(RMORHP.ORHCUSCHN, '-', RMORHP.ORHCUSNUM) As 'Customer Number', RMCUSP.CUSCUSNAM As 'Customer Name', RMORHP.ORHDELDTE As 'Delivery Date', Count(RMORHP.ORHORDNUM) As 'Order Count'"
             "FROM BIDW_DataLake.erms.RMORHP RMORHP, BIDW_DataLake.eRMS.RMCUSP RMCUSP"
             "WHERE (RMORHP.ORHDELDTE Between 20181010 And 20181011) AND RMORHP.ORHORDQTY > 0 AND RMCUSP.CUSCUSCHN = RMORHP.ORHCUSCHN AND RMCUSP.CUSCUSNUM = RMORHP.ORHCUSNUM AND RMCUSP.CUSDFTDCN = 505"
             "GROUP BY CONCAT(RMORHP.ORHCUSCHN, '-', RMORHP.ORHCUSNUM), RMCUSP.CUSCUSNAM, RMORHP.ORHDELDTE"
             "ORDER BY [Delivery Date], [Customer Number]")
df = pd.read_sql_query(SQLCommand, cnxn)
#cursor.execute(SQLCommand)
#for row in cursor:
#    print('row = %r' % (row,))
cnxn.close()
```

Comment: Your `pyodbc.connect()` function isn't valid Python syntax. You have no commas separating each argument to the function and the keywords (those to the left of the `=`) shouldn't be encapsulated within `" "`.

Comment: @AdamMitchell: it is correct Python syntax, just a `str` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLCommand is missing spaces between each line and this can trigger your error. I added spaces after " in lines 2 to 5.

```
SQLCommand =("SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(RMORHP.ORHCUSCHN, '-', RMORHP.ORHCUSNUM) As 'Customer Number', RMCUSP.CUSCUSNAM As 'Customer Name', RMORHP.ORHDELDTE As 'Delivery Date', Count(RMORHP.ORHORDNUM) As 'Order Count'"
             " FROM BIDW_DataLake.erms.RMORHP RMORHP, BIDW_DataLake.eRMS.RMCUSP RMCUSP"
             " WHERE (RMORHP.ORHDELDTE Between 20181010 And 20181011) AND RMORHP.ORHORDQTY > 0 AND RMCUSP.CUSCUSCHN = RMORHP.ORHCUSCHN AND RMCUSP.CUSCUSNUM = RMORHP.ORHCUSNUM AND RMCUSP.CUSDFTDCN = 505"
             " GROUP BY CONCAT(RMORHP.ORHCUSCHN, '-', RMORHP.ORHCUSNUM), RMCUSP.CUSCUSNAM, RMORHP.ORHDELDTE"
             " ORDER BY [Delivery Date], [Customer Number]")
```

Comment: This was the issue. Thank you. It works fine after that adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

I think your connection string is not appropriate

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};
       SERVER=test;
       DATABASE=test;
       UID=user;
       PWD=password')
```

Check your ODBC version

Comment: it is not valid Python syntax for `str` literals